# Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set state value based on result of a promise method. For optimistic updates I am setting state value before an asynchronous operation. If operation fails state is reset

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({notify: this.props.notif});
}

render(){
    return(
        <Switch
          onValueChange={(val) => this.toggleNotifications(val)}
          disabled={! this.props.connected}
          value={this.state.notify}
        />
    )
}

toggleNotifications(val: boolean){
    this.setState({notify: val});
    mmSetNotification(val).catch(() => this.setState({notify: !val}));
}
```

I am using async method to set notification value using network call which will update user object

```
async function mmSetNotification(checked: boolean) : Promise {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Meteor.call('setNotification', checked, (error, result) => {
           if(error){
               reject(error);
           }else{
               resolve();
           }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this.setState` instead mutating `this.state`

[**DOCS:**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

```
toggleNotifications(val: boolean){
  this.setState({notify: val});
  mmSetNotification(val).catch(() => this.setState({notify: !val});
}
```

Comment: Same behaviour observed with this.setState also ```mmSetNotification(val).catch(() => this.setState({notify: !val}));```

Comment: Added to original question description

Comment: Are you sure that your network call returns an error? you can see this [example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=p().catch(err%20%3D%3E%20console.log(err))%0A%0Aasync%20function%20p()%20%3A%20Promise%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20reject('error')%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%7D%0A) and it works fine

Comment: Yea, It can return an error. The example shown above is a simple one. A complex method can reject methods if a specific criteria is not met

Comment: Can you log the value of `val` before you call `mmSetNotification` and in `catch` body?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118874/discussion-between-sergeybaranyuk-and-reku).